# How to run a Python script in another project folder which itself is dependent on scripts?

Tags: python

There are many answers on running Python modules from another folder but they don't work for me because the module I'm trying to import itself is dependent on other modules in that folder.

- dir/file_to_import.py
- destination.py

`file_to_import` is getting imported successfully but the modules inside it aren't running.
For e.g.

file_to_import.py is dependent on a module named scraper.py and when I import file_to_import.py and run my code, it gives this error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scraper'`

Comment: You should show the code of how you import "scraper". Is it "import .scraper"?

Comment: I've tried, `from dir.file_to_import import class_to_import` and `import dir.file_to_import`.

Comment: When you do `import dir.file_to_import` try adding `.` in front of `dir`, `import .dir.file_to_import`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding a `__init__.py` to your `dir` directory.

This tells `python` that the folder you're dealing with is a module.

The file can be blank, but generally contains setup code for the module.